# Can we have document for when to use getScriptLock GetUserLock and GetDocumentLock

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Use is not so extensive. I read but I can not imagine the use case and when to apply the LockService in Apps Script. There are three different locks.

```js
 var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();// BEGIN - start lock here
    try {
      lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds.');
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b> Server Busy please try after some time <p>")
      // In case this a server side code called asynchronously you return a error code and display the appropriate message on the client side
      //return "Error: Server busy try again later... Sorry :("
  }
  
  //Then my stuff here
  
 //finaly 
 lock.releaselock();
 }
```

I am writing form data from my published webapp. Web app is accessed by username and password; that means only used by specific users. The form data is being saved in Google sheet where prevously Google Form used to save responses.
I have problem when two users submits form data, sometime one user's data is being replaced by another in the same row. To prevent that I wanted to implement getScriptLock()/Documentlock or Userlock. But it seems one or other problem reamin there. Some lock prevent another user to submit data [ at web app - message is submited] but actually in google form nothing is logged. Very frastating. Which of lockservice do you think I should serve my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

- prevents concurrent access
- ensure data input are executed on a first-come-first-served basis
- (similar to above) avoid data input messing up
- allow setting a 'queue time'

Are you writing the responses to sheet by something like `getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, cols).setValues(values)`?

I think `appendRow(values)` ensure they are inserted one after another.